# Are there more functions set in the insert equation option of Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations, help-files

Good morning, I wanted to know if there are more default functions in Microsoft Word math environment to insert style functions like for example

[image]

Specifically, I am interested in knowing if there are commands for functions that are predetermined such as Taylor expansion, Trigonometric Identity, Fourier Series, Pythagorean Theorem and others that appear in the Office.com option. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Unless the developers have left some "easter eggs" in Word, you can see all the built-in ones by looking at File->Options->Proofing->AutoCorrect->MathAutoCorrect  or Equation Tab->Conversions Group->Equation Options->Math AutoCorrect... Here,  all I see is the ones you have + \identitymatrix. So I'm wondering whether I have misunderstood the question. You can of course *add your own*, but they won't be "default".

Comment: @yokki Ok, thanks for your collaboration, in conclusion they could be added but they would not be predetermined! At one point I thought more functions were coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.webnots.com/how-to-use-math-autocorrect-shortcuts-in-microsoft-office/ there is a list of math macros defined:

```
!!                  ‼
...                 …
::                  ∷
:=                  ≔
\above              ┴
\acute              ́
\aleph              ℵ
\alpha              α
\Alpha              Α
\amalg              ∐
\angle              ∠
\aoint              ∳
\approx             ≈
\asmash             ⬆
\ast                ∗
\asymp              ≍
\atop               ¦
\bar                ̅
\Bar                ̿
\because            ∵
\begin              〖
\below              ┬
\bet                ℶ
\beta               β
\Beta               Β
\beth               ℶ
\bigcap             ⋂
\bigcup             ⋃
\bigodot            ⨀
\bigoplus           ⨁
\bigotimes          ⨂
\bigsqcup           ⨆
\biguplus           ⨄
\bigvee             ⋁
\bigwedge           ⋀
\binomial           (a+b)^n=∑_(k=0)^n▒(n¦k)a^k b^(n-k)
\bot                ⊥
\bowtie             ⋈
\box                □
\boxdot             ⊡
\boxminus           ⊟
\boxplus            ⊞
\bra                ⟨
\break              ⤶
\breve              ̆
\bullet             ∙
\cap                ∩
\cases              Ⓒ
\cbrt               ∛
\cdot               ⋅
\cdots              ⋯
\check              ̌
\chi                χ
\Chi                Χ
\circ               ∘
\close              ┤
\clubsuit           ♣
\coint              ∲
\cong               ≅
\coprod             ∐
\cup                ∪
\dalet              ℸ
\daleth             ℸ
\dashv              ⊣
\dd                 ⅆ
\Dd                 ⅅ
\ddddot             ⃜
\dddot              ⃛
\ddot               ̈
\ddots              ⋱
\defeq              ≝
\degc               ℃
\degf               ℉
\degree             °
\delta              δ
\Delta              Δ
\Deltaeq            ≜
\diamond            ⋄
\diamondsuit        ♢
\div                ÷
\dot                ̇
\doteq              ≐
\dots               …
\doublea            
\doubleA            
\doubleb            
\doubleB            
\doublec            
\doubleC            ℂ
\doubled            
\doublee            
\doubleE            
\doublef            
\doubleF            
\doubleg            
\doubleG            
\doubleh            
\doubleH            ℍ
\doublei            
\doubleI            
\doublej            
\doubleJ            
\doublek            
\doubleK            
\doublel            
\doubleL            
\doublem            
\doubleM            
\doublen            
\doubleN            ℕ
\doubleo            
\doubleO            
\doublep            
\doubleP            ℙ
\doubleq            
\doubleQ            ℚ
\doubler            
\doubleR            ℝ
\doubles            
\doubleS            
\doublet            
\doubleT            
\doubleu            
\doubleU            
\doublev            
\doubleV            
\doublew            
\doubleW            
\doublex            
\doubleX            
\doubley            
\doubleY            
\doublez            
\doubleZ            ℤ
\downarrow          ↓
\Downarrow          ⇓
\dsmash             ⬇
\ee                 ⅇ
\ell                ℓ
\emptyset           ∅
\emsp
\end                〗
\ensp
\epsilon            ϵ
\Epsilon            Ε
\eqarray            █
\equiv              ≡
\eta                η
\Eta                Η
\exists             ∃
\forall             ∀
\fraktura           
\frakturA           
\frakturb           
\frakturB           
\frakturc           
\frakturC           ℭ
\frakturd           
\frakturD           
\frakture           
\frakturE           
\frakturf           
\frakturF           
\frakturg           
\frakturG           
\frakturh           
\frakturH           ℌ
\frakturi           
\frakturI           ℑ
\frakturj           
\frakturJ           
\frakturk           
\frakturK           
\frakturl           
\frakturL           
\frakturm           
\frakturM           
\frakturn           
\frakturN           
\frakturo           
\frakturO           
\frakturp           
\frakturP           
\frakturq           
\frakturQ           
\frakturr           
\frakturR           ℜ
\frakturs           
\frakturS           
\frakturt           
\frakturT           
\frakturu           
\frakturU           
\frakturv           
\frakturV           
\frakturw           
\frakturW           
\frakturx           
\frakturX           
\fraktury           
\frakturY           
\frakturz           
\frakturZ           ℨ
\frown              ⌑
\funcapply
\G                  Γ
\gamma              γ
\Gamma              Γ
\ge                 ≥
\geq                ≥
\gets               ←
\gg                 ≫
\gimel              ℷ
\grave              ̀
\hairsp
\hat                ̂
\hbar               ℏ
\heartsuit          ♡
\hookleftarrow      ↩
\hookrightarrow     ↪
\hphantom           ⬄
\hsmash             ⬌
\hvec               ⃑
\identitymatrix     (■(1&0&0@0&1&0@0&0&1))
\ii                 ⅈ
\iiiint             ⨌
\iiint              ∭
\iint               ∬
\Im                 ℑ
\imath              ı
\in                 ∈
\inc                ∆
\infty              ∞
\int                ∫
\integral           1/2π                    ∫_0^2π    ▒ⅆθ/(a+b sin θ)=1/√(a^2-b^2)
\iota               ι
\Iota               Ι
\itimes             ⁢
\j                  Jay
\jj                 ⅉ
\jmath              ȷ
\kappa              κ
\Kappa              Κ
\ket                ⟩
\lambda             λ
\Lambda             Λ
\langle             〈
\lbbrack            ⟦
\lbrace             \{
\lbrack             [
\lceil              ⌈
\ldiv               ∕
\ldivide            ∕
\ldots              …
\le                 ≤
\left               ├
\leftarrow          ←
\Leftarrow          ⇐
\leftharpoondown    ↽
\leftharpoonup      ↼
\leftrightarrow     ↔
\Leftrightarrow     ⇔
\leq                ≤
\lfloor             ⌊
\lhvec              ⃐
\limit              lim_(n→∞)⁡〖(1+1/n)^n〗=e
\ll                 ≪
\lmoust             ⎰
\Longleftarrow      ⟸
\Longleftrightarrow ⟺
\Longrightarrow     ⟹
\lrhar              ⇋
\lvec               ⃖
\mapsto             ↦
\matrix             ■
\medsp
\mid                ∣
\middle             ⓜ
\models             ⊨
\mp                 ∓
\mu                 μ
\Mu                 Μ
\nabla              ∇
\naryand            ▒
\nbsp
\ne                 ≠
\nearrow            ↗
\neg                ¬
\neq                ≠
\ni                 ∋
\norm               ‖
\notcontain         ∌
\notelement         ∉
\notin              ∉
\nu                 ν
\Nu                 Ν
\nwarrow            ↖
\o                  ο
\O                  Ο
\odot               ⊙
\of                 ▒
\oiiint             ∰
\oiint              ∯
\oint               ∮
\omega              ω
\Omega              Ω
\ominus             ⊖
\open               ├
\oplus              ⊕
\otimes             ⊗
\overbar            ¯
\overbrace          ⏞
\overbracket        ⎴
\overline           ¯
\overparen          ⏜
\overshell          ⏠
\parallel           ∥
\partial            ∂
\perp               ⊥
\phantom            ⟡
\phi                ϕ
\Phi                Φ
\pi                 π
\Pi                 Π
\pm                 ±
\pmatrix            ⒨
\pppprime           ⁗
\ppprime            ‴
\pprime             ″
\prec               ≺
\preceq             ≼
\prime              ′
\prod               ∏
\propto             ∝
\psi                ψ
\Psi                Ψ
\qdrt               ∜
\quadratic          x=(-b±√(b^2-4ac))/2a
\rangle             〉
\Rangle             ⟫
\ratio              ∶
\rbrace             }
\rbrack             ]
\Rbrack             ⟧
\rceil              ⌉
\rddots             ⋰
\Re                 ℜ
\rect               ▭
\rfloor             ⌋
\rho                ρ
\Rho                Ρ
\rhvec              ⃑
\right              ┤
\rightarrow         →
\Rightarrow         ⇒
\rightharpoondown   ⇁
\rightharpoonup     ⇀
\rmoust             ⎱
\root               ⒭
\scripta            
\scriptA            
\scriptb            
\scriptB            ℬ
\scriptc            
\scriptC            
\scriptd            
\scriptD            
\scripte            ℯ
\scriptE            ℰ
\scriptf            
\scriptF            ℱ
\scriptg            ℊ
\scriptG            
\scripth            
\scriptH            ℋ
\scripti            
\scriptI            ℐ
\scriptj            
\scriptJ            
\scriptk            
\scriptK            
\scriptl            ℓ
\scriptL            ℒ
\scriptm            
\scriptM            ℳ
\scriptn            
\scriptN            
\scripto            ℴ
\scriptO            
\scriptp            
\scriptP            
\scriptq            
\scriptQ            
\scriptr            
\scriptR            ℛ
\scripts            
\scriptS            
\scriptt            
\scriptT            
\scriptu            
\scriptU            
\scriptv            
\scriptV            
\scriptw            
\scriptW            
\scriptx            
\scriptX            
\scripty            
\scriptY            
\scriptz            
\scriptZ            
\sdiv               ⁄
\sdivide            ⁄
\searrow            ↘
\setminus           ∖
\sigma              σ
\Sigma              Σ
\sim                ∼
\simeq              ≃
\smash              ⬍
\smile              ⌣
\spadesuit          ♠
\sqcap              ⊓
\sqcup              ⊔
\sqrt               √
\sqsubseteq         ⊑
\sqsuperseteq       ⊒
\star               ⋆
\subset             ⊂
\subseteq           ⊆
\succ               ≻
\succeq             ≽
\sum                ∑
\superset           ⊃
\superseteq         ⊇
\swarrow            ↙
\tau                τ
\Tau                Τ
\therefore          ∴
\theta              θ
\Theta              Θ
\thicksp
\thinsp
\tilde              ̃
\times              ×
\to                 →
\top                ⊤
\tvec               ⃡
\ubar               ̲
\Ubar               ̳
\underbar           ▁
\underbrace         ⏟
\underbracket       ⎵
\underline          ▱
\underparen         ⏝
\uparrow            ↑
\Uparrow            ⇑
\updownarrow        ↕
\Updownarrow        ⇕
\uplus              ⊎
\upsilon            υ
\Upsilon            Υ
\varepsilon         ε
\varphi             φ
\varpi              ϖ
\varrho             ϱ
\varsigma           ς
\vartheta           ϑ
\vbar               │
\vdash              ⊢
\vdots              ⋮
\vec                ⃗
\vee                ∨
\vert               |
\Vert               ‖
\Vmatrix            ⒩
\vphantom           ⇳
\vthicksp
\wedge              ∧
\wp                 ℘
\wr                 ≀
\xi                 ξ
\Xi                 Ξ
\zeta               ζ
\Zeta               Ζ
\zwnj               ‌
\zwsp
~=                  ≅
+-                  ±
-+                  ∓
<<                  ≪
<=                  ≤
->                  →
>=                  ≥
>>                  ≫
```

Comment: That information is already clear to me, I obtained it from various documents including [https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~khitron/Equation%20Editor.pdf], [http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf] and many others found on the internet.

Comment: My question is directed to know if there are other commands like the ones you mentioned (eg \ quadratic, \ binomial, \ integral ...) where when entering your code, the Word equation editor allows you to express it in its default form, as they appear in the image found in the initial message. That is, if I want to use the Taylor expansion, just adding some command before the character "\" appears in its equation form

Comment: As far as I know, the list I provided is comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration,

Answer (score 1):

In the reply on Replied on December 4, 2017 in the thread [Creating an equation in Word 2013](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-an-equation-in-word-2013/9daa4481-c173-4c18-87a5-7b97108a2c8a) a user links to UnicodeMath as a potential source to help answer OPs question in the thread.

Doing a little more research I found [Linear format equations using UnicodeMath and LaTeX in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8) which links Unicodemath to MS Word.

If you would want to see a more detailed list of commands you can look into the following documentation: [UnicodeMath (pdf)](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.1.pdf), [Unicode Nearly Plain-Text Encoding of Mathematics](https://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf) or for a more condensed version [The Word 2007/2010 Equation Editor (pdf)](https://mathiho.sitehost.iu.edu/doc/equation-editor-shortcut-commands.pdf)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).